# How to use user input to assign into function()

Tags: r, function

I am trying to use the user input and assign it to num and I am using function as it can run the whole program. But I can't assign the user input into num. Here is my code.

```
pam=function(num){
  {num=as.integer(readline(prompt="Enter a number:"))
  fact=1
  if(num<0)
    return(NULL)
  else{
    for(i in 1:num)
      if(num>0)
        fact=fact*i
      }
    print(paste("The factorial of", num,"is", fact))
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to have `num` as argument if you ask it in the function.
Try:

```
pam=function(){
  num=as.integer(readline(prompt="Enter a number:"))
  fact=1
  if(num<0)
    return(NULL)
  else{
    for(i in 1:num)
      if(num>0){
        fact=fact*i
      }
    print(paste("The factorial of", num,"is", fact))
  }
}

pam()
Enter a number:3
[1] "The factorial of 3 is 6"
```